# Black bars on render Blender

Tags: blender

Demostration of black bar.

[image: sample image]

[Link to .blend file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WZX_oWhlDmzrNsj_vrA1_7iU0J2bYsED/view?usp=sharing)

Pls help to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compositing nodes are adding the letterbox effect. You can remove or disconnect the letterbox group node to prevent it being applied.

First choose the compositing screen -

[image: goto compositing screen]

Use the mouse wheel [image: MW] to zoom in and out and middle mouse button [image: MMB] to pan around so you can find the letterbox node to the right of the node tree. Connect the node before the letterbox to the composite node. You do this by dragging from one yellow socket to the other.

[image: adjusted nodes]

Then go back to the default screen (or other that you were using before).